# MSSQL Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP5.6

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install the mssql driver in ubuntu 16.04 with php5.6. All the components installed without error but after a restart of the apache2 nothing occurs. The driver is not recognized, I tried an 8 tutorials I found on google and nothing worked.

My environment is with the following configuration:

```
PHP 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please share your apache config and the code which is supposed to use the driver. Also which code samples you've tried

Comment: I copyedited slightly, but to improve your question, you should link to the 8 examples that didn't work, otherwise we don't have the full context of your question.

Comment: I try [this](https://coderwall.com/p/21uxeq/connecting-to-a-mssql-server-database-with-php-on-ubuntu-debian) and i see it: `locale is "pt_BR.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Default database being set to BDUstop
Error 20017 (severity 9):
 Unexpected EOF from the server
 OS error 115, "Operação agora em progresso"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
 Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server`

Comment: I solved part of the problem with ISQL I could connect and make consultations but when trying to connect with PHP (codeiginter) have the following output: 
`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source, SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect

Filename: odbc/odbc_driver.php

Line Number: 141

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/mssql/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once`